# Generate a matrix with for loop and splice another column

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to generate a matrix like

```
1 1 1 0
2 1 1 0
3 1 1 0
...
```

I have code like

```
data=[]
for z in range(1,10)
    for y in range(1,9)
        for x in range(1,8)
            data.append([x,y,z])
a=[0.0]*504 (9*8*7=504)
```

the output is a list, with a length of 504, and each element is a list
like [1, 1, 1], and the 0-column can not be connected to the matrix.
What is the better way to generate my matrix?

Comment: Are you allowed to use numpy?

Comment: I think check your for loop iterators.

Comment: Yes, I can use numpy, but this is the only way I know to generate the the specific scheme of x y z

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```py
data=[]

for z in range(0, 10):
   for w in range(1, 3):
      for x in range(0,10):
         for y in range(0,10):
              data.append([w,x,y,z])

for i in data:
   print(str(i).replace(',', '').replace('[', '').replace(']', ''))
```

Does it give you what you want?

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want it just to be printed right, but in the data structure, like I want an index for each element in the matrix, so can you change like ```data[0,3]```is the 0, ```data[1,0]```is the 2.

Answer (score 0):

What if you reversed appending the data to the matrix? Also, keep in mind that the `x` will change with each iteration of `for x in range(0,5)`. If you want `x` as a fixed number, you can change `x` to 0 or 1 or anything.

```
data=[]
for x in range(0,10):
    for y in range(1,9):
        for z in range(1,8):
            for x1 in range(1,7):
                data.append([x1,z,y,x])

for da in data:
    print(da)
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 0]
[2, 1, 1, 0]
[3, 1, 1, 0]
[4, 1, 1, 0]
[5, 1, 1, 0]
....
```

With Last number fixed:

```
data=[]
for x in range(1,10):
    for y in range(1,9):
        for z in range(1,8):
            data.append([z,y,x,0])

for da in data:
    print(da)
```

If you don't want the list, you can replace:

```
for da in data:
    print(da)
```

with this:

```
for da in data:
    print(' '.join([str(d) for d in da]))
```

You can also try this:

```
data=[]
for x in range(1,10):
    for y in range(1,9):
        for z in range(1,8): 
           data.append([z,y,x,0])
i=1
for da,dat in enumerate(data):
    data[da][0]=da+1
print(data)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want an index for each element in the matrix, so can you change like ```data[0,3]```is the 0, ```data[1,0]```is the 2.

Comment: You want the index of 0 in the matrix?

Comment: I want to access to any element with index.

Comment: So you want the index of elements from matrix

Comment: Not print, but in data structure, I want a array of  504x4, not a list with 504 element, and each element has 4 elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with list comprehension. Try:

```py
data = [[z, y, x, 0] for x in range(1, 10) for y in range(1, 9) for z in range(1, 8)]

print(data[0][3]) # 0
print(data[1][0]) # 2

print(data[:10]) # will print the first ten rows
```

If you want a numpy array with dimension 504×4, then just make sure you have `import numpy as np` at the beginning and then add `data = np.array(data)` at the end of the code; then you can use `data[1, 0]` to retrieve `2`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like this ?

```py
data = [[0, y, z, 0] for z in range(1,10)
                     for y in range(1,9)
                     for x in range(1,8)]

for i, d in enumerate(data):
    data[i][0] = i+1
print(data)
```

```
[[1, 1, 1, 0],
 [2, 1, 1, 0],
 [3, 1, 1, 0],
.
.
.
 [502, 8, 9, 0],
 [503, 8, 9, 0],
 [504, 8, 9, 0]]
```